# htaccess rule works one server but not another

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my local server I have an .htaccess file with these rules:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(?!menu/)([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^menu/([^\.]+)$ item.php?url=$1 [NC,L]
```

It works on the server on my computer but the rules do not work on my public testing server. My computer is a mac mini and I am using MAMP. The testing server is a MAC OS X Server version 10.8.5. Also, I know .htaccess files are enabled and working on the testing server.

The problem on the testing server is that it doesn't recognize menu/ in the url. It will recognize menu but not with the slash at the end. What I am trying to do is get a url that looks like /menu/soft-taco redirect to item.php?url=soft-taco.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a trailing optional slash in your both rules and try reversing the order of rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^menu/([^/.]+)/?$ item.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Nice troubleshooting, +1. Hope it works for the OP. :)

Comment: That did the trick, anubhava! Thank you so much for your help.